# How can you prevent propagation of events from a MUI (v4) Slider Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI v4 Slider (specifically used as a range slider: https://v4.mui.com/components/slider/#range-slider) component inside an expandable component in a form, however, the `onChange` handler for the Slider component immediately propagates up into the parent and triggers the `onClick` handler which controls the hide/show.

In the child:

```
import { Slider } from '@material-ui/core';

export const MySliderComponent = ({ setSliderValue }) => {
  let onChange = (e, value) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setSliderValue(value);
  }
  return <Slider onChange={onChange} />
}
```

In the parent:

```
let [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
let toggle = (e) => setExpanded(!expanded);

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div className={'control'} onClick={toggle}>Label Text</div>
    <div hidden={!expanded}>
      <MySliderComponent />
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Points:

- when I click inside the slider component, but not on the slider control, it does not trigger the toggle in the parent
- when I click on the slider control, the event immediately (on mouse down) triggers the toggle on the parent
- throwing a `e.preventDefault()` in the `onChange` handler has no effect
- using Material UI v4 (no I can't migrate to 5)

I don't understand why the `onChange` would trigger the parent's `onClick`. How do I prevent this, or otherwise include a Slider in expandable content at all?

Edit:

After further debugging I found that if I removed the call to setSliderValue, that the parent did not collapse/hide the expanded content. Then I checked the state of `expanded` and it seems to be resetting without a call to `setExpanded`. So it looks like the parent component is re-rendering, and wiping out the state of the useState hook each time.

Comment: Which component are you using as the parent?

Comment: At first I tried the `Accordion`, but when I got this bug I implemented the same thing with a `div` (as above) but got the same behavior. -- I labeled each of the code blocks as parent and child.

Comment: I edited the example for clarity. I named the child `MySliderComponent`

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for me in a simmilar problem:

1. Give your parent component a unique id (for readability)

   div id="parent" className={'control'} onClick={toggle}
2. Modify the parent's onClick handler (toggle):

   ```
    let toggle = (e) => {
      if (wasParentCLicked()) setExpanded(!expanded);

      function wasParentCLicked() {
        try {
           if (e.target.id === "parent") return true;
         } catch(error) {

         }
         return false;
      }
    }
   ```

For further help refer to the official documentation of the Event.target API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target